# Spark Streaming not reading files from local directory in Windows

Tags: apache-spark, real-time, spark-streaming

```
public class StreamingWordCount implements Serializable { 

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext("local[2]", "JavaWordCount",
            new Duration(1000));
    JavaDStream<String> data = jssc.textFileStream("D:/krishna/").cache();
    data.foreach(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {

        public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
            List<String> output = rdd.collect();
            System.out.println("Sentences Collected from files " + output);
            return null;
        }
    });

    data.print();
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
  }
}
```

I am using Spark standalone on Windows 8.

Does JavaStreamingContext only works for HDFS directories?

Click for output: [This is output on console, Sentence collected from files is empty. I tried changing the directory, files. But still code is not picking files. This is my first code in Spark Streaming. Kindly help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIlc2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the batch time interval by **5 ms to 10 ms** if any job will take more than provided batch time the jssc.awaitTermination() method will wait for completion pending job and automatically handle the batch timing.

Comment: Do not agree, reference please.

Comment: it will not read the old files, for test you can put file in given directory while running.